# How do I use OpenCV's remap function?

Tags: python, opencv, remap

Here's the simplest possible test case for remap():

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
inimg = np.arange(2*2).reshape(2,2).astype(np.float32)
inmap = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]).astype(np.float32)
outmap = np.array([[10,10],[10,20],[20,10],[20,20]]).astype(np.float32)
outimg = cv2.remap(inimg,inmap,outmap,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
print "inimg:",inimg
print "inmap:",inmap
print "outmap:",outmap
print "outimg:", outimg
```

and here's the output:

```
inimg: [[ 0.  1.]
 [ 2.  3.]]
inmap: [[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
outmap: [[ 10.  10.]
 [ 10.  20.]
 [ 20.  10.]
 [ 20.  20.]]
outimg: [[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

As you can see, outimg produces 0,0, and it's not even in the correct shape.  I expect a 20x20 or 10x10 image with interpolated values from range 0 to 3.

I've read all the documentation. It and everyone on SO states you input an array (a map) of starting points, a map of ending points, and then remap() will put all the values in img into their new positions, interpolating any empty space.  I'm doing that, but it just doesn't work.  Why?  Most examples are for C++.  Is it broken in python?

Comment: I've given an answer but I can expand on it a bit with a more simple example if you answer me the question...what is the output you were expecting there? Obviously an output of shape `(2, 2)` first off but what values were you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting an output shape of 20x20, since that's the largest value.  Most other points are interpolated.

Comment: I'm expecting an output of[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1]  ....  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3]]

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This is just a simple misunderstanding of the documentation, and I don't blame you---it took me a few fumblings to understand it, too. The docs are clear, but this function probably doesn't work in the way you expect; in fact, it works in the *opposite* direction from what I expected at first.

What `remap()` *doesn't* do is take the coordinates of your source image, transform the points, and then interpolate. What `remap()` *does* do is, for every pixel in the destination image, lookup *where it comes from* in the source image, and then assigns an interpolated value. It needs to work this way since, in order to interpolate, it needs to look at the values around the source image at each pixel. Let me expand (might repeat myself a bit, but don't take it the wrong way).

From the [`remap()` docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#cv2.remap):

> **map1** – The first map of either `(x,y)` points or just `x` values having the type `CV_16SC2` , `CV_32FC1` , or `CV_32FC2` . See `convertMaps()` for details on converting a floating point representation to fixed-point for speed.
>
> **map2** – The second map of `y` values having the type `CV_16UC1` , `CV_32FC1` , or none (empty map if `map1` is `(x,y)` points), respectively.

The verbiage here on `map1` with "the *first* map of..." can be confusing. Remember, these are strictly the coordinates of where your image gets mapped *from*...the points are being mapped *from* `src` at `map_x(x, y), map_y(x, y)` and then placed into `dst` at `x, y`. And they should be the same shape of the image you want to warp them *to*. Note the equation shown in the docs:

```
dst(x,y) =  src(map_x(x,y),map_y(x,y))
```

Here `map_x(x, y)` is looking up `map_x` at the rows and columns given by `x, y`. Then the image value is evaluated at those pixels. It's looking up the mapped coordinates of `x, y` in `src`, and then assigning that value to `x, y` in `dst`. If you stare at this long enough, it starts to make some sense. At pixel `(0, 0)` in the new destination image, I look at `map_x` and `map_y` which tell me the location of the corresponding pixel in the source image, and then I can assign an interpolated value at `(0, 0)` in the destination image by looking at near values in the source. This is sort of the fundamental reason why `remap()` works this way; it needs to know *where a pixel came from* to get the neighboring pixels to interpolate.

### Small, contrived example

```
img = np.uint8(np.random.rand(8, 8)*255)
#array([[230,  45, 153, 233, 172, 153,  46,  29],
#       [172, 209, 186,  30, 197,  30, 251, 200],
#       [175, 253, 207,  71, 252,  60, 155, 124],
#       [114, 154, 121, 153, 159, 224, 146,  61],
#       [  6, 251, 253, 123, 200, 230,  36,  85],
#       [ 10, 215,  38,   5, 119,  87,   8, 249],
#       [  2,   2, 242, 119, 114,  98, 182, 219],
#       [168,  91, 224,  73, 159,  55, 254, 214]], dtype=uint8)

map_y = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]], dtype=np.float32)
map_x = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 10]], dtype=np.float32)
mapped_img = cv2.remap(img, map_x, map_y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
#array([[153, 251],
#       [124,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

So what's happening here? In this case it's easiest to examine the matrices:

```
map_y
=====
0  1
2  3

map_x
=====
5  6
7  10
```

So the destination image at (0, 0) has the same value as the source image at `map_y(0, 0), map_x(0, 0) = 0, 5` and the source image at row 0 and column 5 is 153. Note that in the destination image `mapped_img[0, 0] = 153`. No interpolation is happening here since my map coordinates are exact integers. Also I included an out-of-bounds index (`map_x[1, 1] = 10`, which is larger than the image width), and notice that it just gets assigned the value `0` when it's out-of-bounds.

### Full use-case example

Here's a full-fledged code example, using a ground truth homography, warping the pixel locations manually, and using `remap()` to then map the image from the transformed points. Note here that my homography transforms `true_dst` *to* `src`. Thus, I make a set of however many points I want, and then calculate where those points lie in the source image by transforming with the homography. Then `remap()` is used to look up those points in the source image, and map them into the destination image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read images
true_dst = cv2.imread("img1.png")
src = cv2.imread("img2.png")

# ground truth homography from true_dst to src
H = np.array([
    [8.7976964e-01,   3.1245438e-01,  -3.9430589e+01],
    [-1.8389418e-01,   9.3847198e-01,   1.5315784e+02],
    [1.9641425e-04,  -1.6015275e-05,   1.0000000e+00]])

# create indices of the destination image and linearize them
h, w = true_dst.shape[:2]
indy, indx = np.indices((h, w), dtype=np.float32)
lin_homg_ind = np.array([indx.ravel(), indy.ravel(), np.ones_like(indx).ravel()])

# warp the coordinates of src to those of true_dst
map_ind = H.dot(lin_homg_ind)
map_x, map_y = map_ind[:-1]/map_ind[-1]  # ensure homogeneity
map_x = map_x.reshape(h, w).astype(np.float32)
map_y = map_y.reshape(h, w).astype(np.float32)

# remap!
dst = cv2.remap(src, map_x, map_y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
blended = cv2.addWeighted(true_dst, 0.5, dst, 0.5, 0)
cv2.imshow('blended.png', blended)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Remap for warping]

Images and ground truth homographies from the [Visual Geometry Group at Oxford](https://web.archive.org/web/20190227071148/http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data5.html).

Comment: A lot here to digest.  I appreciate the thought and depth put into it.  Your homography example is EXACTLY what I am trying to do, just with different images and challenges.  Point is I need to know how to use remap()

In your code, "map_ind = H.dot(lin_homg_ind)
map_x, map_y = map_ind[:-1]/map_ind[-1]" (apologies, SO doesn't allow formatting in comments) - THATS what I need to understand.

Comment: src(map_x(x,y),map_y(x,y)) - this says to me that map_x provides points to take from src and put into dst[x,y] - which is exactly what I'm trying to do. ?

Comment: @johnktejik "this says to me that map_x provides points to take from src and put into dst[x,y] - which is exactly what I'm trying to do." Yes, precisely. `map_x[1, 0]` holds the coordinate from `src` that gets put into `dst[1, 0]`. Btw you can do inline code using backticks; \`this\` produces `this`. Feel free to send me an email (on the website in my profile) and I'd be happy to help you out with specific problems in implementation. I've used these functions a lot.

Comment: @johnktejik added the short code example that we discussed over email. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Alex!  :)  It's a very detailed answer which you didn't need to do!

Comment: @johnktejik I expanded on it well since I haven't seen another post go into detail on this function, so I think it will prove to be helpful in the future when people try to use `remap()`. Anyways, the larger code example was already sitting in a file. :)

Answer (score 6):

```py
warped = cv.warpPerspective(img, H, (width, height))
```

is equivalent as

```py
idx_pts = np.mgrid[0:width, 0:height].reshape(2, -1).T
map_pts = transform(idx_pts, np.linalg.inv(H))
map_pts = map_pts.reshape(width, height, 2).astype(np.float32)
warped = cv.remap(img, map_pts, None, cv.INTER_CUBIC).transpose(1, 0, 2)
```

where the `transform` function is

```py
def transform(src_pts, H):
    # src = [src_pts 1]
    src = np.pad(src_pts, [(0, 0), (0, 1)], constant_values=1)
    # pts = H * src
    pts = np.dot(H, src.T).T
    # normalize and throw z=1
    pts = (pts / pts[:, 2].reshape(-1, 1))[:, 0:2]
    return pts
```

---

`src_pts` : `[[x0, y0], [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]` (each row is a point)

`H, status = cv.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts)`