# Finding corresponding pixel coordinate of a single point before and after cv2.remap

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Let's begin by saying that i have a static image, called it `leftFrame`.

This frame is passed to method `cv2.remap(leftFrame, map1, map2, cv2.INTER_LANCZ0S4,0)`, so that every pixel from original image (`leftFrame`) is reallocated to a new position. Given that map1 and map2 is output from `cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(MLS, dLS, RL, PL,imgShape,cv2.CV_16SC2)`, with MLS, dLS, RL, PL had been calculated before.

Things are done well,

HOWEVER, now I just want to get the corresponding pixel coordinate of a single point in the new frame, given the original pixel coordinate of that point in the initial, original frame (leftFrame).

How can I achieve it?

The code is simplified to be like this:

```
Left_Stereo_Map = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(MLS, dLS, RL, PL,imgShape,cv2.CV_16SC2)
leftCap = cv2.VideoCapture(PORT)
 while (True):
   # Collect image continously
   ret1, leftFrame = leftCap.read()
   Left_nice = cv2.remap(leftFrame, Left_Stereo_Map[0], Left_Stereo_Map[1], cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
   original_x = PREDEFINED_X
   original_y = PREDEFINED_Y
   x_after = ?
   y_after = ?

   cv2.waitkey(1)
```

Thanks everyone for spending your time reading this question. Wish you safe in this time!

Comment: Did you look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520123/how-do-i-use-opencvs-remap-function)?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to separately call initUndistortRectifyMap in the opposite direction. The returned map1/2 contain the mapping you need, respectively for the x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a very fast search algorithm to find the index of the new coordinate point with the least distance from your original point. A reverse search. This index will be corresponding to the original point in the mapped image.

```py
def _map(x, y, mapx, mapy):
    i = x
    j = y

    # Calculate the distance of original point and out guessed point
    delta_old = abs(mapx[y, x] - x) + abs(mapy[y, x] - y)
    while True:
        next_i = i
        next_j = j
        # Searching the 8 neighboring points for the smallest distance
        for dx in range(-1, 2):
            for dy in range(-1, 2):
                # Make sure we don't go out of the image using a max-min
                search_point_x = max(min(i+dx, mapx.shape[1] - 1), 0)
                search_point_y = max(min(j+dy, mapx.shape[0] - 1), 0)
                delta_x = abs(mapx[search_point_y, search_point_x] - x)
                delta_y = abs(mapy[search_point_y, search_point_x] - y)
                # If the distance of the new point was less than
                # the distance of the older point, replace the point
                if delta_old >= delta_x + delta_y:
                    delta_old = delta_x + delta_y
                    next_i = search_point_x
                    next_j = search_point_y

        # If the newly found point is no better than the old point we stop
        if next_i == i and next_j == j:
            break
        else:
            i = next_i
            j = next_j

    return next_i, next_j
```

As the mapped point must be somewhere close to the original coordinates, hence we can quickly search the neighborhood points using gradient decent!