# Transform an image in Python specifying target coordinates for each pixel

Tags: python, image-processing, transformation, cartography

I am looking for a Python image processing package that will allow me to take a source image, and to create a new image by specifying a pixel location to take each pixel in the source image *to*, on a pixel-by-pixel basis (i.e. more general than an affine transformation). Specifically, if the original image is a 2-d array A, and we have an array of x-coordinates (indices of A) X and an array of y-coordinates (indices of A) Y, then an each element of Z, Z(i,j) goes to a pixel in the new image A' at (X(i,j),Y(i,j)).

Basically I am trying to do (x,y)->(f(x,y), g(x,y)), but quickly.

Currently I am doing this "by hand" in numpy as a nested loop iterating over pixels in the source image, and I feel certain there is something in a package out there that will do this much more quickly, though I've not found it. Something *like* cartopy clearly has something of this sort going on to do image transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I discovered this is possible with OpenCV using [remap](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4). However, remap solves the inverse problem, i.e. for every pixel in the destination image, a pixel location is specified at which to sample the source image. I merely needed to invert my problem.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46524544/1528634) on Stack Overflow is a good starting point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure I could improve this much further without adding further examples: answer includes both a link to the documentation and an example. Happy to add something else specific if required.