# Python image manipulation; pinch or implode image not on a circle, but on a line

Tags: python, image-processing

For a given image, I want to move pixels by 'pinching' the image without changing the actual size of the image. A good example can be [seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64069808/7052826).

[image]

See this example image above, from the answer linked above. Here pixels around the center are pulled towards the center. Thus, the deformation of the image is based on a circle. In other words, pixels on the left of the center are pulled towards the right, pixels above the center are pulled down and pixels top-left of the circle will be pulled in a down-right direction.

My desired outcome is to pinch the image pixels only in one direction. Thus, instead of pixels being pulled towards the center of a circle, I would want pixels to be pulled towards a horizontal (or vertical) line. Pixels above the horizontal line are pulled down, pixels below will be pulled up.

I expect I could create the desired outcome by iteratively using a circle pinch across every column of the image and taking the column that has the circle center, but this seems very in-efficient.

Any python library that can achieve this would be acceptable.

Comment: answer in link uses [Wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.0/wand/image.html) and maybe it has other method which can work as you expect. Often deformation could be created using some mask/matrix with information how far move pixel - and maybe it has function to use own matrix for this.